# Got Error“Expects arg[0] to be uint8 but float is provided" when running tensorflow c++, who knows how to fix it?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Part of my codes is as follows,

```
IplImage *pImg = cvLoadImage("img.bmp"， 1); 
IplImage *pImgF = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(pImg),IPL_DEPTH_32F , 3);

cvConvert(pImg, pImgF);

tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
tensorflow::TensorShape({ 1, input_height, input_width, 3 }));
auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();

float *pSourceRow = (float *)pImgF->imageData;
int x, y, c;
int depth = 3;

for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    const float* source_row = pSourceRow + (y * width * depth);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        const float *source_pixel = source_row + (x * depth);
        const float* source_B = source_pixel + 0;
        const float* source_G = source_pixel + 1;
        const float* source_R = source_pixel + 2;

        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 0) = *source_R;
        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 1) = *source_G;
        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, 2) = *source_B;
    }
}
const Tensor& resized_tensor = input_tensor;

Status run_status = session->Run({ { input_layer, resized_tensor } },
    { output_layer }, {}, &outputs);

if (!run_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
    return -1;
}
```

After running , the run_status shows error"Expects arg[0] to be uint8 but float is provided". Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution? Thanks